# Apple TV with a wifi router but no internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, itunes, appletv

I have a wifi router connected to a cable modem and I can connect Apple tv to the wifi network and link to it from laptops and iOS devices no problem. I currently have a temporary problem with the Internet connection and I now get an error when I try to play a video on my laptop via Apple tv in iTunes.

Why does Apple tv require an Internet connection to play content that is already downloaded on my PC?

When I play local content on my iPad air 2 it works fine. The problem only seems to occur on my PCH.

The videos I'm playing are listed in iTunes as local (no cloud symbol). Some I purchased on iTunes, some not. All were manualy added to iTunes because the process for sharing between devices forces the content to be re-downloaded from the Apple Store which is a waste of bandwidth.
The content on my iPad was transferred from my laptop by dragging and dropping into iTunes for the same reason given above.
I have the latest aTV and the latest version of iTunes.

Comment: Your playing videos that only exist on your network or are they iTunes purchases?

Comment: what is your aTV and what is the software

Comment: @ramhound Edited to answer your question. And the content is already downloaded.

Comment: @atais Edited to answer your question.

Comment: Alright;  If you are connecting your Apple TV to your Computer through the iTunes feature.  Provided your computer has a internet connection, the only videos you should need an internet access to play, are those videos you purchase from iTunes.

Comment: I have only 1 video in my iTunes, in "Home Video" tab in iTunes (not sure of translation, 3rd one) but it plays fine without the Internet. I have just tested... The only thing I can think of is recommending you another app to AirPlay wideos to aTV. I use Beamer and I am very satisfied.

Comment: @atais ok, thanks for testing that. I guess there is some issue with how I have iTunes set up.

Comment: @ramhound not sure what you mean, why do I need Internet access to play content purchased from iTunes if it's already downloaded?

Comment: @atais there is no home video tab in iTunes. Am I correct in assuming that your test was on an iOS device, not on a windows pc?

Comment: Yes; There is but you have to enable home sharing, it needs Internet to verify you have the rights to view it, otherwise I could just give you my downloaded videos. I have an Apple TV connected by Home Sharing and I can play non-ITunes videos without an active internet connection but a connection to my router